# How to use alias name in a Kivy Language import?

Tags: kivy

I am having troubles to assign alias names when importing classes in the Kivy Language. The documentation I am following is [here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#special-syntaxes):

To import something from python:

```
#:import name x.y.z
```

Is equivalent to:

```
from x.y import z as name
```

I created a reduced version of my problem. `pieces.py` is inside the package pieces (with its respective `__init__.py`) and the `pieces.kv` is in my working folder.

**pieces/pieces.py**

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class PieceA(Button):
    pass
class PieceB(Button):
    pass
class PieceC(GridLayout):
    pass
```

**pieces.kv**

```
#:import Boo pieces.pieces.PieceA
#:import Foo pieces.pieces.PieceB
#:import Too pieces.pieces.PieceC
<Boo>:
    text: "A"
<Foo>:
    text: "B"
<Too>:
    rows: 2
    Boo:
    Foo:
```

The import is as stated in the documentation but the aliases Boo, Foo and Too are not 
being recognized. There are also many other versions of this that unexpectedly works **if I use the original name of the class but not the alias name**:

```
#:import Boo pieces.pieces
<PieceA>:
    text: "A"
<PieceB>:
    text: "B"
<PieceC>:
    rows: 2
    PieceA:
    PieceB:
```

Even if I substitute `#:import Boo pieces.pieces` for `#:import Boo pieces.pieces.PieceA`. It continue working as long as I use the original name of the classes but I cannot use alias names. **How do I use an alias name when I import a class in the Kivy Language?**

---

I also added here my other 2 files in case you want to test.

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

Builder.load_file('pieces.kv')

class Gallery(GridLayout):
    pass

class GalleryApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Gallery()

GalleryApp().run()
```

**gallery.kv**

```
<Gallery>:
    cols: 3
    PieceA:
    PieceB:
    PieceC:
```

Comment: It might be important to specify that I am using Kivy v1.7.0,, just in case this is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to do is actually possible, but at the very least this import syntax does not have that purpose and is behaving properly. That is, the `#:import` syntax applies only to the python parts of the kv file, so for instance you could include code like

```
#:import Boo pieces.pieces.PieceA
...
...
<SomeWidget>:
    Button:
        on_press: some_other_widget.add_widget(Boo())
```

This would do what you expect, with Boo being a standard python alias for PieceA.

However, when the kv file is parsed I'm not aware of a way to alias the names of class rules. I'm also not sure why you'd want or need to (not that this means there isn't a reason!), why not just refer to them as PieceA, PieceB etc.?

Comment: this is part of other files and I had a class name conflict. It took me a while to find out what was happening so I ended changing the name of one of the classes since the import didn't work. I see your point that the alias name just works on the python side, but I disagree that the `#:import` syntaxes just apply to the Python side. If I don't put the import then it does not work correctly.

Comment: Re: your last sentence, that seems strange, I don't use any imports and the rules are applied fine - I think the import should not be necessary for defining rules, only for use in the python code.

Comment: https://github.com/inclement/fourierdroid is a project I was playing with that works fine but uses no #:import in the kv file

Comment: Well, it doesn't work without the import. You can test it with my example.

Comment: In fourierdroid, you are using one Kivy(`fourier.kv`) file that is called because the App has its name `FourierApp`. Therefore, there is no need of imports. This give me an idea though. I could assign the alias name in the imports of the Python file and call my `pieces.kv` with the Kivy Builder.